# Java 8 Supplier without double colon

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am unable to create a Supplier without using :: notation. All the tutorials seem to be using :: to get the method out.

```
Function<String, Object> beanFactory = m_context::getBean;
Function<Void, IRCPublic> ircPublicSupplier = a -> (IRCPublic) beanFactory.apply("developerPublicConnection");
ircPublicSupplier.apply(null);
```

How would I go about turning line 2 into a single line statement to create a Supplier, and simply being able to use '.get()' . I can use '.apply(null)' but that just seems dirty.

Thank you!

Comment: @Vulcan Supplier doesn't take any input arguments. So the a is rejected. The correct syntax is in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it inline:

```
Supplier<IRCPublic> ircPublicSupplier = 
    () -> (IRCPublic) beanFactory.apply("developerPublicConnection");
```

Or you could also wrap the `IRCPublic` instance returned by the `beanFactory` in a method:

```
IRCPublic getIrcPublic() {
    return (IRCPublic) beanFactory.apply("developerPublicConnection");
}
```

And then use the `::`:

```
Supplier<IRCPublic> ircPublicSupplier = this::getIrcPublic;
```

This assumes that the above line is in the same class where the `getIrcPublic` method is defined.

Comment: I was unaware that to supply no arguments you needed to specify empty brackets. A lot of tutorials omit this. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

Intellij to the rescue. I defined it the long way round:

```
Supplier<IRCPublic> ircPublicSupplier = new Supplier<IRCPublic>() {
        @Override
        public IRCPublic get() {
            return (IRCPublic) beanFactory.apply("developerPublicConnection");
        }
    };
```

And Intellij shortened it to:

```
Supplier<IRCPublic> ircPublicSupplier = () -> (IRCPublic) beanFactory.apply("developerPublicConnection");
```